# Having an issue with javascript Date()

Tags: javascript, date

I am using - `new Date(2014, 5, 2)`. But it is not showing the proper date.

When i do `console.log(new Date(2014, 5, 2));` on the console it returns - `Mon Jun 02 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`. Why `June`? Should not it be `May`?

Comment: `Date` is 0 indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The month index starts from 0, not from 1... Then 0 is January...

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Comment: Same for day also i think.

Comment: Exactly, but the question was refered to month ...

Answer (score 1):

Month index starts from Jan.

0 - Jan 
1 - Feb..

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the ***[docs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)***.

> JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11.

Answer (score 0):

No June is correct, May was last month. Check out w3schools example of the format you're trying to use: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Answer (score 0):

Months are zero based. i.e. January is 0 February is 1 etc.

[W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)